# How to add a realistic neck shadow between torso and face?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shadows

I'm trying to recreate image (1), my current progress is (2).
How do I add that realistic neck area that is in image (1), to my image (2)?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use layers like this. Merge them down. Sample the green colour from the object and paint over the chest area (and hands) using a brush set to color mode. These areas need to be the same shade of green before trying to blend them. Then use a soft edged brush set to normal mode to paint the shadow and to cover over the obvious line, then use the smudge tool to blend.  Add a texture layer on top, mask it, then set the layer blending mode overlay.

A rough example:

[image]